# Como eu tenho acesso a um objeto que foi usado para renderizar uma lista?

Tags: javascript, html

Eu usei um Objeto que está dentro de um array, para renderizar uma lista. Agora eu precisava recuperar esse Objeto para rederizar uma nova lista com novos Objetos. Como eu faria para recuperar esse objeto? Tentei utilizar click com addEventListener mas ele está retornando o el

inteiro.

```
window.onload = function(){
    //your code here
    const ListaFrutas = [
        {
            'fruta':'Mamão',
            'Preço':3.9,
            'imagem':'1'
        },
        {
            'fruta':'Laranja',
            'Preço':0.7,
            'imagem':'2'
        },
        {
            'fruta':'Manga',
            'Preço':2.3,
            'imagem':'3'
        },
        {
            'fruta':'Melão',
            'Preço':2.8,
            'imagem':'4'
        },
        {
            'fruta':'Melancia',
            'Preço':4.1,
            'imagem':'5'
        },
        {
            'fruta':'Maçã',
            'Preço':2.4,
            'imagem':'6'
        },
        {
            'fruta':'Banana',
            'Preço':1.7,
            'imagem':'7'
        },
    ]
    
    const frutas = document.getElementById('produtos')
    const frutasCarrinho = document.getElementById('cestaDoCliente')
    ListaFrutas.map((n) => {
        frutas.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', `<li class="listaDeFrutas"><img src="assets/img/${n.imagem}.jpg" alt="">${n.fruta}</li>`);
    })
    ListaFrutas.map((n) => {
        frutasCarrinho.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', `<li class="listaDeFrutas hide"><img src="assets/img/${n.imagem}.jpg" alt="">${n.fruta}</li>`);
    })    

    const lista = []
    let frutasQuery = document.querySelectorAll('.listaDeFrutas, .hide');
    let hideClass = document.querySelectorAll('.hide');

    frutasQuery.forEach((el) => {

        el.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
            el = 
            console.log(el)
        })
    })

}
```

```
        <div id="content-produtos" class="flex" >
            <ul id="produtos" >

            </ul>
        </div>

        <h2>Sua Cesta</h2> 
        <div id="content-lista-produtos-cliente" class="flex">

            <ul id="cestaDoCliente"></ul>

            <div id="content-totalCompras" class="flex flex-row-end">
                <span class="flex">
                    TOTAL
                </span>
                <input type="button" id="mostraTotalCompra">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: `el = console.log(el)` - isso não faz o menor sentido, se queria apenas imprimir os elementos, bastaria fazer `console.log(frutasQuery)` ou `frutasQuery.forEach(el => console.log(el))`. E [não use `map` para percorrer o array](/a/535576/112052) (poderia ser `forEach` ou até mesmo um `for` simples). De qualquer forma, não deu pra entender o que vc quer fazer...

Answer (score -2):

Bom dia Fabio, beleza?

Olha não entendi bem sua pergunta mas vamos lá.
No se código não tem nenhum bloco que adiciona um elemento no array `ListaFrutas`, se você quer renderizar um novo elemento seria só dar um `push` nesse array e passar um loop que nem você fez usando o `map`.

Eu recomendaria usar o `forEach` ou for para fazer esse loop ao invés de usar o `map`. O `forEach` foi feito para executar loops sem retornos então seria o ideal.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).